# codesandbox - Cannot find module PACKAGE or its corresponding type declarations

Tags: javascript, typescript, import, npm-publish, codesandbox

I built and released a npm package called [schemez](https://github.com/TakitoTech/schemez). On my local system via vscode, it works great with no errors and plenty of Typescript support. On codesandbox, its erroring out with `Cannot find module 'schemez' or its corresponding type declarations.ts(2307)` even though the code is compiling.

Sample - https://codesandbox.io/s/fluent-json-schema-vs-schemez-vs-typebox-645s2j

Why is this occurring?

Answer (score 0):

For me, this issue is popping up. When I open console it seems to be a CORS issue with the specific package. It might be a temporary problem, because I can not find many issues regarding this in 2022, although there is a unanswered one here

https://github.com/codesandbox/codesandbox-client/issues/6834